# I have a shopping cart with session, how can I display multiple sides for one menu?

Tags: php, arrays

```
if($_POST["action"] == "add_side") {  
     foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values) {  
        if($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_id'] == $_POST["product_id"]) {  

            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['side_name'] = $_POST["side_name"]; 
            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['side_price'] = $_POST["side_price"];
        }  
    }  
}
```

I would like it to display multi sides for a menu but it is only displaying the last added side and ignoring the rest.... how can I change that and have multi sides for one menu. Been struggling with this for a while. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are not adding a slide, but updating one if it exists with the same data. what you want to do is to check if the productId exists, if not then add on a new product onto the end of the session array. Like so:

```
 if($_POST["action"] == "add_side")  
  {  
       if(!in_array($_POST["product_id"], array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], 'product_id'))){

           $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = [

               'product_id' => $_POST["product_id"],
               'side_name' => $_POST["side_name"],
               'side_price' => $_POST["side_price"]

           ];
       }
  }
```

Comment: still does not work, instead can I check if the side_id is not in the shopping cart add value where product_id = post [product_id]

Comment: what about this doesn't work? Errors or is the array in the incorrect format?

Comment: when I add the side, nothing comes up but theres no errors

Comment: do you have session_start() at the top of your script? Can you do a var_dump of $_SESSION["shopping_cart"] and $_POST and edit the qeustion with the results

Comment: I have made it in such a way that if product_id already exist, quantity will go up one but now I just need it to stay like that but just the sides will be added ... For example Cheese Burger   x2 sides Lemon Juice, Apple Juice, extra cheese and so on